# Django: migration file depends on removed Django-APP

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

In a Django project I've been asked to [remove completely an installed app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20897851/uninstall-django-completely);

I've already:

- removed all code references
- removed from `INSTALLED_APPS`
- checked there are no db tables around

so far, so good; the problem raises when running:

```sh
$> python manage.py migrate
```

since there is a migration file around with the following:

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('THE REMOVED APP', '0001_initial'),
        ...

    operations = [
        ...
```

It says:

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: 
Migration xxx.yyy dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('THE REMOVED APP', '0001_initial')
```

**May I change the migration file and commit the following?**

```
@@ -14,7 +14,6 @@ class Migration(migrations.Migration):

     dependencies = [
-        ('THE REMOVED APP', '0001_initial'),
     ]
```

Comment: It depends on the contents of the migration file. If the migration has the dependency, then the migration might have a reference to that app (e.g create a foreign key that points to `other_app.DeletedModel`. Running that migration would fail because `other_app.DeletedModel` does not exist.

Comment: this is not the case in this particular, but would be the way to go in that case @Alasdair?

Comment: You might be able to [squash the migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#squashing-migrations) to remove the references to the deleted app.

Answer (score -1):

You can probably remove the existing migrations file and run migrations again.
Note: This could be dangerous in production machines in certain conditions ([check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404461/can-i-delete-the-django-migration-files-inside-migrations-directory)) so choose wisely and use this solution if you are not in production.

1. Delete `*.pyc` files and `__pycache__` if any.
2. Delete the migrations files and run:

   $> python manage.py makemigrations

   $> python manage.py migrate

Comment: You don't want to delete migrations ever in case your project is already in production or used by distributed team
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404461/can-i-delete-the-django-migration-files-inside-migrations-directory

Comment: @iklinac answer is that depends. Here user is likely to re-install django too for solution to this

Comment: your answer states "You can always remove the existing migrations file" , he is just removing one app/module from his project not nuking it down xD